# What object paints JTable grid lines

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I would like to override whatever method is responsible for rendering JTable grid lines.  I want to create a specific grid line that only prints a short vertical line at the outer edges of each cell.

I created a CellRenderer and a custom border to do this originally because I had thought that maybe the component rendered in a table had a default border and that's how they showed up, I see my custom rendered border but it's inside the cell so this obviously was not where the grid lines are painted.

Can anyone tell me which method is responsible for rending grid lines?

Comment: it's a private methods in BasicTableUI (paintGrid), no easy way to take over except a nearly complete re-implementation of the painting (mostly c&p)

Comment: BasicTableUI is part of the LAF right?

Comment: part of custom L&F touched this properties

Comment: Okay, I managed to get a custom grid, it's not the best way but I created my own TableUI and copied the java source for the paint() method and copied the private methods it depends on, now I can modify the private paintGrid() method and call JTable's setUI(new MyCustomTableUI())

Comment: You can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to kleopatra's comment I was able to arrive at the results I wanted.  I did this by creating a custom TableUI that extended BasicTableUI and I overrode Paint(Graphics g) which is responsible for painting table information.  Once a new TableUI was created I used JTable's setUI method to set the UI to my own custom implementation.